# How to remotely check if Apache server responds?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, monitoring

I have 2 servers. One of them often crashes. I want to send a SMS to my phone when it crashes.

I wrote this simple bash script in another server and put it in crontab to run every 10 minutes.

```
wget --spider http://mywebsite.com || php sendsms.php
```

Is this the right way? Sometimes I get SMS, but I see that server is running without any problem.

Comment: Is the `--spider` really necessary? If the site is large, it could take a long time, and if the first page works, you already know Apache is working. Are there particular pages (perhaps CGI scripts) which may malfunction for other reasons? Then maybe use (one of) those as your test case.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see from the output of `wget --spider ...` why `wget` has failed. That information is emailed to the user running the script or, if you use

```
MAILTO=your.email@address.com
```

you can redirect it to your email account for review.

If there are spurious network or DNS errors you can do a double check to see if unavailability was temporary, and thereby reducing the number of false positives:

```
wget --spider -a /var/tmp/wget_test.log http://mywebsite.com || (sleep 10; wget --spider http://mywebsite.com ) || php sendsms.php
```

Note that I have made the first try, append output to a log file (instead of  printing to stderr). This way you don't get an email every 10 minutes if things run fine.

Every `wget` run first prints a date-timestamp and url when it tries that url.
You will be able to review all runs that fail the first `wget` and pass the second by matching the date-timestamp from the emailed output of the second `wget` to that from the log file.